# Add custom meta tag in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, meta-tags

I am adding a custom meta tag to my layout page

```html
<meta name="description" content="{{metaDiscription}}"/>
```

And In Controller:

```js
$scope.metaDiscription = "adding custom discription";
```

and check it in "View page source", it is showing meta content as it is in crawlers(not evaluating the angular crawl).
How can I update meta tags in angularjs which can be shown in "view page source" of the page ?

Here is my full code:

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.directive(
        'customMetaTag',
        function() {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                template: '<meta name="description" content="{{metaDescription}}"></meta>',
                replace: true,
                link: function(scope) {
                    scope.metaDescription = 'adding custom discription';
                }
            }


        }
    )
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'/>
  <custom-meta-tag></custom-meta-tag>
</head>

<body>

 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you should show us your directive definition.

Comment: What you see in view page sourde is the source of the page. Not the DOM after it has been modified by angular, so that's quite expected. If you want web crawlers, who don't execute JavaScript, to see the real value of the meta tag, you shouldn't use JavaScript to set the description.